# PHPUnit Testing repository with `with` method

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I've been trying to solve this for a while.
I'm testing a repository that uses the 'with' method however I can't figure out how to write the tests to cover the method.

```
        $this->entity
        ->shouldReceive('with')
        ->once()
        ->andReturnSelf();
```

doesn't seem to work

Comment: You don't mock Models. You literally use [factories](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories). So create a factory related to that model, so when you do `with`, it returns something back.